# How to locate the element using Relative Xpath for RadioButton Scenario within http://jqueryui.com

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to automate RadioButton scenario in Selenium through the website - http://jqueryui.com/checkboxradio/

I tried using xpath by CssSelector, customised xpath, but nothing worked for me. I finally had to use absolute xpath(not the best practice though) for the code to work.

```
public class CheckBoxAndRadioButtons {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver" , "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Selenium Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/checkboxradio/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='demo-frame']")));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        WebElement radiobox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/fieldset[1]/label[1]/span[1]"));
        boolean isDisplayedstatus = radiobox.isDisplayed();
        System.out.println(isDisplayedstatus);
        boolean isEnabledstatus = radiobox.isEnabled();
        System.out.println(isEnabledstatus);
        boolean isSelectedstatus = radiobox.isSelected();
        System.out.println(isSelectedstatus);

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        List<WebElement> ele = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type ='radio']"));
        for(WebElement we:ele) {
            if(!we.isSelected()) {
                we.click();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below code.I think webdriver click is not working.So I have used javascript executor to click on element.

```
WebElement radiobox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='radio-1']"));
        boolean isDisplayedstatus = radiobox.isDisplayed();
        System.out.println(isDisplayedstatus);
        boolean isEnabledstatus = radiobox.isEnabled();
        System.out.println(isEnabledstatus);
        boolean isSelectedstatus = radiobox.isSelected();
        System.out.println(isSelectedstatus);

        List<WebElement> ele = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[starts-with(@id, 'radio')]"));
        for(WebElement we:ele) {
            if(!we.isSelected()) {
                JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",we);
                System.out.println("Clicked : " + we.getAttribute("id"));
               // we.click();
            }
        }
```

Output:

```
true
true
false
Clicked : radio-1
Clicked : radio-2
Clicked : radio-3
```

Answer (score 2):

If I am correctly interpreting your problem that you don't want to use the full xPath, I found that the following will identify the same radio element you grabbing:

```
"//fieldset[1]/label[1]/span[1]"
```

Then to find the subsequent checkboxes (the two after 'New York'), you could use

```
"//fieldset[1]/label[2]/span[1]"
```

and

```
"//fieldset[1]/label[3]/span[1]"
```

Answer (score 2):

Radio button is an **input** element with **radio** type and easy way is interact with it. For that you can use id `radio-1`.

If you want locate radio button by label text, for example "New York", you can use xpath below:

```
//label[normalize-space(.)='New York']/following-sibling::input[@type='radio'][1]
```

Code will be:

```
WebElement radioButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[normalize-space(.)='New York']/following-sibling::input[@type='radio'][1]");
boolean isDisplayed = radioButton.isDisplayed();
System.out.println(isDisplayed);
boolean isEnabled = radioButton.isEnabled();
System.out.println(isEnabled);
boolean isSelected = radioButton.isSelected();
System.out.println(isSelected);
```

---

You also can use `label` element to select using `//label[normalize-space(.)='New York']`, but `isSelected()` will not work and you'll have to check `ui-state-active` css class availability:

```
// Using label
WebElement radioButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[normalize-space(.)='New York']"));

// Select radio by clicking on label
radioButton.click();

// Check if radio selected by css class of the label
boolean selected = radioButton.getAttribute("class").contains("ui-state-active");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to select `New York` radio button you can use the following xpath.

```
//label[contains(@class,'ui-checkboxradio-radio-label') and text()='New York']
```

Answer (score 1):

To click on the *radio button* adjacent to the text **New York** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  package demo;

  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class Q55111127_Chaitanya_Maligi {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("start-maximized");
          options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); 
          WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
          driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/checkboxradio/");
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='demo-frame']")));
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='widget']//fieldset//label[@for='radio-1']"))).click();
          System.out.println("Clicking of CheckBox Completed");
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Clicking of CheckBox Completed
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: radio_button_jQuery]